# how to make this function work in order with the tkinter label

Tags: python, function, tkinter

so im having issues with the function in my code and it doesnt display a fail in the console so i just dont know whats wrong.
basically im trying to make a clicker kinda thing where everytime the button is clicked it increases the exp variable by one and then updates the label, but it isnt really working. also the level part doesnt need much attention except if there is something you would like to say about it.

```
window = Tk()

window.title ("test")



#variables
exp2 = 0
level = 1
exp = 0

#exp function
def function ():
    global exp,exp2, level
    exp2 = exp + 1
    if exp <100:
        exp = 0
        level + 1
    else:
        return function()



#labels
label_1 = Label (window, text = (exp2,"/100"), bg = 'white', fg ='black')
label_2 = Label (window, text = "exp" , bg = 'white', fg ='black')
label_3 = Label (window, text = "level", bg = 'white', fg ='black')
label_4 = Label (window, text = level, bg = 'white', fg ='black')

#buttons
button_1 = Button (window, text = 'click for xp', command = function())

#placements
label_1.grid (column = 3, row = 2)
label_2.grid (column = 3, row = 1)
label_3.grid (column = 5 , row = 1)
label_4.grid (column = 5, row = 2)
button_1.grid (column = 4, row = 4 )

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command=function()` should be `command=function` (without the `()`).  Also think again the logic inside `function()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Function():
    global exp, level
    exp += 1
    if exp > 100:
        exp=0
        level+=1
    label.config(text=exp)
```

should work for you, you dont actually need the exp2 variable. The label.config is there for you

Answer (score 0):

```
    #python3
    from tkinter import *
    window = Tk()
    window.title ("test")

    #variables
    #exp2 = 0

    exp = 0
    level=0
#exp function
    def function ():
        global exp,exp2, level
        label_1.configure(text="%d" %(exp)+"/10")
        exp+=1
        if exp==10:
                level+=1
                label_4.configure(text=level)
                exp=0
                

     



    #labels
    label_1 = Label (window,text="%d" %(exp)+"/10", bg = 'white', fg ='black')
    label_2 = Label (window, text = "exp", bg = 'white', fg ='black')
    label_3 = Label (window, text = "level", bg = 'white', fg ='black')
    label_4 = Label (window,  bg = 'white', fg ='black')
    #buttons
    button_1 = Button (window, text = 'click for xp', command = function)
    #placements
    label_1.grid (column = 3, row = 2)
    label_2.grid (column = 3, row = 1)
    label_3.grid (column = 5 , row = 1)
    label_4.grid (column = 5, row = 2)
    button_1.grid (column = 4, row = 4 )

    window.mainloop()
```

Even though I don't really understand the question, I hope that it answered your question. You can stop the continuous count by removing the label_1.after(500,function). If this answer your question, vote

Comment: I tried to use 10 instead of 100. So that when it gets to 10, the level updates by 1

Comment: OP just wants to update the `exp` and `level` whenever the button is clicked.  So the `after()` should not be used.

Comment: I have edited the answer, does that answer your question?